# Android ProGuard : keep class not working

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

It works well for apps from other projects.
It does not apply from any moment.

vo file keep failed.

```
-keep class **.vo.** { *; }
-keep class **.model.** { *; }
```

The location of the proguard-rules2.pro file is under the app folder.

I did this gradle setting like this.

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.keystore
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules2.pro'

    }
    debug {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Why does not `-keep class **.vo.** { *; }` in Pro Guard files work?

I finally used it like this.

```
-keepnames class ** {*; }
```

Pro Guard is still ignored.

I guess you can not call proguard-rules2.pro.